# How to delete the first slide while remaining on the current slide

Tags: slick.js

On the afterChange passing to the second slide i remove the first slide and a translation put automaticly the second slide to le left.
Is it possible to stay on the second slide after remove de first one

my slick slider is in centerMode and only used with swipe :
`$('#car').slick({ slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1, adaptiveHeight: true, infinite: false, arrows: false, dots: false, centerMode: true, centerPadding: '30px', autoplay: false });`

I tried a lot but no solution
For example i tried to chain remove and slickGoTo the new first but no way
//$('#car').slick('slickRemove',0);
//$('#car').slick('slickGoTo',0,true);